# How to define a function without args or return vaule in java8?

Tags: java, lambda

How to define a function without args or return vaule?

```
Class Foo {
    public void setBar(String bar){...};
    public String getBar(){...};
}

? getter = Foo::getBar;
? setter = Foo::setBar;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your missing pieces are `Function` and `BiConsumer`

```
// Equivalent to: Function<Foo, String> getter = foo -> foo.getBar();
Function<Foo, String> getter = Foo::getBar

// Equivalent to: BiConsumer<Foo, String> setter = (foo, str) -> foo.setBar(str);
BiConsumer<Foo, String> setter = Foo::setBar
```

Comment: Not quite, you'd need `Function` and `BiConsumer`.

Comment: I guess you meant `Function`?